# How can I copy a file in a bash script and rename it while copying and place it in the same directory

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, rename, file-copy

How would I copy a file "file.doc" and rename it while copying to "file_copy.doc" and place it in the same directory ?

And this only by calling the script and adding the file name in the argument:

```
bash launch_copyer file.doc
```

Comment: If you don't insist on Bash, I think there are ready-made tools for that as well.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I find the wording really confusing here. Why are `mv` and `cp` insufficient? Could we have an example?

Comment: Rename the file to **what**?  Copy the file to **where**?? What if there is already a file named **file_copy.doc**??

Answer (score 4):

No need for `bash` here, any standard `sh` interpreter implementation will do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
ret=0
for file do
  dir=$(dirname -- "$file")
  case $dir in
    (*[!/]*) dir=$dir/ # handle / and // specially
  esac
  base=$(basename -- "$file")
  name=${base%.*}
  name=${name:-$base} # don't consider .bashrc the extension in /foo/.bashrc
  ext=${base#"$name"}
  new_file=$dir${name}_copy$ext
  cp -- "$file" "$new_file" || ret=$?
done
exit "$ret"
```

(assumes the file and dir names don't end in newline characters).

(of course, that will also work with `bash` since `bash` is one of those *standard `sh` interpreters*.)

For a `bash`-specific solution, you could try:

```
#! /bin/bash -
ret=0
re='^((.*/)?[^/])(([^/]*)(\.))?([^/]*)/*$'
for file do
  if [[ $file =~ $re ]]; then
    if [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[5]} ]]; then
      suffix=_copy.${BASH_REMATCH[6]}
    else
      suffix=${BASH_REMATCH[6]}_copy
    fi
    cp -- "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}$suffix" || ret=$?
  else
    printf >&2 '%s\n' "$0: Error: refusing to copy $file"
    ret=1
 fi
done
exit "$ret"
```

Comment: Like mine, this also seems to fail if the file has no dotted extension

Comment: @roaima, well, it meant to address that, but there was a typo. Should work now. It also addresses things like `foo.d/bar`, `foo/.bashrc`, `/foo` properly which also solution don't...

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP is asking for a bash solution. Here is one that does.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -f $1 && $(($# != 1)) ]]; then 
    printf '%s\n' "Provide a filename"
    exit 1
fi

inFile="$1"
fileExt="${1#*.}"
destFile="${1%.*}"

cp -- "$inFile" "${destFile}_copy.$fileExt"  # As suggested, so the files that start with a dash are not ignored.
```

Comment: That will fail in a number of cases like with those arguments: `-foo-`, `foo.tar.gz`, `/foo/bar`, `foo.d/bar.doc`. I'm not sure why you insist on the argument being a regular file or symlink to regular file, that's not part of the requirement. Error messages should be displayed on stderr.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You've a point there. I should have used `--` to indicate end of options.  Well the `.doc` suggests a file. That check is not necessarily either.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that is even shorter indeed. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
ss=0
for file do
    cp -fp -- "$file" "${file%.*}_copy.${file##*.}" || ss=$?
done
exit $ss
```

This fails if `file` does not have a dot extension part. If you need that to work use [Stéphane Chazelas's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204338/100397).

Comment: This won't copy files starting with a dash like `-foo` as mentioned.

Comment: @holasz fixed that. Not planning to fix dot-extension files.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp /example/directory/file.doc /example/directory/file_copy.doc
```

this specifies the file name and will do what you want

Comment: That's not what OP asked either. What it does is just copy source file to dest file. There is a shorter step though. `cp /path/to/dir/{file.doc,file_copy.doc}`  Again, the OP wan'ts to use the positional parameter `$1`

Comment: @val0x00ff, more like `cp /path/to/dir/file{,_copy}.doc` here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f "$1" ];
then
  cp -v "$1" _"$1"
  rename -v 's/_(.+?)\./$1_copy\./' _"$1"
fi
```

The script checks if the input file that receives as input exists. In that case, it makes a temporary copy of the file and then renames such copy replacing the first dot in its name with the string `_copy.`

I hope it is what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Shell Provides the following expansion capability, which you can use with commands like mv or cp:

```
$ echo myfile{.sh,.bak}
myfile.sh myfile.bak
$ echo myfile{.sh,.bak1,.bak2}
myfile.sh myfile.bak1 myfile.bak2
$ echo myfile.sh{,.bak}
myfile.sh myfile.sh.bak
$ echo myfile.sh{.bak,}
myfile.sh.bak myfile.sh
```

Tested with the following:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```